# Ubuntu add user access to folder with ssh-key

Tags: 16.04, ssh, directory, users

I would like to know if on my vps. in which Ubutu 16.04 is installed with the access method is key ssh, it is possible to create a user who has access to a single folder (that can upload and modify files) that uses as his login method his ssh key

Comment: Why wouldn't it? Have you tried it, create a new user with limited folder access and a new ssh key?

Comment: This is the perfect answer for your question. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208960/how-to-restrict-a-user-to-one-folder-and-not-allow-them-to-move-out-his-folder